# Monte Carlo Post Processing will not run for DFS lineups

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, montecarlo

```
# simR may need to be deleted
#need to convert this into a function

simR = pd.DataFrame()

# l is a dataFrame that will hold the total points scored by each lineup
l = pd.DataFrame()


## a - m stores diffrent features of the simulation results

a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []
e = []
f = []
g = []
h = []
k = []
m = []

token = True  #GPP or cash
for i in range(len(sim)):
    if token == True:
        p = sim.iloc[i,:][sim.iloc[i,:]<= round(num_l*0.01)] #top 1% 12
        q = sim.iloc[i,:][sim.iloc[i,:]<=round(num_l*0.1)] #top 10% 117
        r = sim.iloc[i,:][sim.iloc[i,:]>round(num_l*0.1)] #remaining 117
        l = val.iloc[i,:]
        
        a.append(i+1)
        b.append(p.count())
        e.append((p.count()/num_sim)*100)
        c.append(q.count())
        f.append((q.count()/num_sim)*100)
        d.append(r.count())
        h.append((r.count()/num_sim)*100)
        g.append((p.count()*4)+(q.count()*.1)-(r.count()*5))
        k.append(l.mean())
        m.append(l.std())
        
    else:
        p = [sim.iloc[i,:][sim.iloc[i,:]<=600]] #top 50%
        r = [sim.iloc[i,:][sim.iloc[i,:]>600]] #bottom 50%
        l = val.iloc[i,:]

        
        a.append(i+1)
        b.append(p.count())
        e.append((p.count()/num_sim)*100)
        d.append(r.count())
        h.append((r.count()/num_sim)*100)
        g.append((p.count()*5)-(r.count()*5))
        k.append(l.mean())
        m.append(l.std())
        
        
        
    if i == 1:
        
        print('Cleaning Data')
        
    elif i==round(num_l*.1):
        print('Data is 10% clean')
        
    elif i==round(num_l*.25):
        print('Data is 25% clean')
    elif i== round(num_l*.5):
        print('Data is 50% clean')
    elif i== round(num_l*.75):
        print('Data is 75% clean')
    elif i== (num_l-1):
        print('Data is 100% clean')
```

I can't figure out why this code will not run.  No error message pops up but it should be cleaning data from the monte carlo simulation I have running.  When I run the kernel, the final product is blank and it should be returning optimal lineups for NBA DFS.  After the post processing, it should format the results of the monte carlo simulation.  I'm not getting an error message at all but the lineups that are printing to csv are blank.  I can gladly post the entire code or email it if that would help.

Comment: Quite a bit of things you need to clean up here, like all the `elif` to check for percent complete (make that a variable), and all those lists. If you want us to help you need to also provide enough code AND full/sample of the dataset. We need to be able to run the code on our end.

Comment: I'd be glad to email the entire program to you to take a look.